# Laratrust Middleware Admin Panel

Tags: laravel, panel, middleware, laratrust

Laratrust is now offering a [panel](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/6.x/usage/admin-panel.html#how-to-use-it) where you can CRUD the roles and permissions. Works like a charm until I use `'permission:access-laratrust'`(for example) as middleware in the configuration. For some odd reason it does not work. I dumped `Auth::user()` but it returns null...?!
I am lost on how this is not working and user returns null. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you dumped `Auth::user()` where?

Comment: In a middleware I created myself and is working in my own defined routes

Answer (score 0):

Add the `web` middleware before the permission check, like so:

```
'middleware' => ['web', 'permission:access-laratrust'],
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem.
I went through xdebug and came to the conclusion that it is necessary to add all the necessary middleware.
In my case this works:

```
'middleware' => ['web', 'auth:admin', 'role:superadmin'],
```

So, it`s necessary to check all middlewares.